# Applet running on 32 bit JRE but not in 64 bit JRE

Tags: java, applet, 32bit-64bit, internet-explorer-11, deployjava

I've been working on an applet using `deployjava.js` and it works fine with **32 bit JRE**. Now I'm trying to test it with **64 bit JRE**, and the applet runs on **64 bit** if I open the `JNLP` file directly, however it doesn't work when I try to run the applet in my web application (using 64 bit IE11 - 64 bit JRE - Windows 8.1).

I've tried to open (in **IE11 64 bit**) another website with an applet and it runs in **64 bit JRE**, so it has to be something about my own applet and configurations. With my applet, the page ends up redirecting to Java download for 64 bit Windows, unless I have **32 bit JRE** installed (so that the applets run on **32 bit JRE** only).

Have anyone encountered this kind of issue? Java code is supposed to be able to run in both `32 or 64 bit JVM`, however I'm not sure why my applet would not run unless there's **32 bit JRE**.

Comment: Run this link `https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp`. it will show you the exact problem with applet or browser or plugin required!! this may help.

Comment: What kind of applet are you running? I have a gut feeling that it use some dependency which is in 32 bit version only and not available for 64.

Comment: Bhumika Thaker, I've ran that link before and it successfully detects the JRE 64 bit version. Since I've opened another website with applet running on 64 bit JRE, I assume that it has to do with my own applet implementation/configuration.

Comment: StackFlowed, it might be possible, although wouldn't it be unable to run on 64 bit JRE when I open the JNLP directly?

Comment: For example, here is a demo applet from Oracle: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/examplesIndex.html). Using depltoolkit_Java2Demo, if I open the JNLP directly then the applet runs on 64 bit JRE. If I open the HTML page on IE11, then it redirects me to the Java download page, unless 32 bit JRE is also installed.